# Sudden error of PyWin32 script

Tags: python, pywin32, winlogon

Python script is tracking logins on a Windows machine, based on (but is not exactly the same as) [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/grawity/896881/a47a685c44321945a7a911669568f0bdaada61e9). It uses PyWin32, which was a bit tricky to set up properly, but once it was done the script had been running smoothly for months - until it suddenly stopped working, seemingly without a reason.

I am unable to determine why the script stopped working. Since there are multiple users I checked if someone 'tampered' with path/system variables or python installation or something similar.

---

**Settings** have remained the same and used to work without a problem. Of course PyWin was installed in env used:

```
(py27) C:\Users\Username>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py27:
#
pip                       9.0.1                    py27_1
pypiwin32                 219                       <pip>
python                    2.7.13                        1
pywin32                   221                       <pip>
requests                  2.14.2                   py27_0
setuptools                27.2.0                   py27_1
vs2008_runtime            9.00.30729.5054               0
wheel                     0.29.0                   py27_0
```

And additional system variables/paths have also been set at the beginning and haven't been changed:

[image]

---

**Error:**
Lately the script always fails, producing the following error when running in PyCharm:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py27\python.exe C:/Python27/LoginTracker/wtsmonitor-svc.py
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site.py", line 177
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

However, when running monitor-svc.py from CMD directly, it produced a little bit different error:

```
C:\Projects\LoginTracker>wtsmonitor-svc.py start
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
wtsmonitor-svc: PyWin32 modules not found
```

Any ideas why does this happen? No installations were changed (that I know of) and can't figure out the reason for the error.

Comment: Your first error message is because the code is expecting there to be `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of the code, and it isn't there.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I'm aware of this and have this line included in code (my code is not the same as the project I linked, although it is based on it). My code used to work, and although it wasn't changed, it now keeps showing these errors.

Comment: What's the actual command that gets executed for `wtsmonitor-svc.py start`? Maybe you forgot to "activate" your venv?

Comment: The corresponding env is activated (py27), however when tested with PyCharm it is specifically selected to always use py27 env (under Project Structure >> Python SDK home path) and also throws error now, while it used to work. Maybe it's something wrong with env all of a sudden? I can make a new one, install PyWin there as well and test  if script works again ...